# Next.JS - Gist's embedded in markdown rendered via dangerouslySetInnerHTML only show after full page load, not React route load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dangerouslysetinnerhtml, embedded-script

I have a series of blog posts stored in MD files, some of these contain multiple Gist embeds in the form of script tags.

The MD contents are rendered to the page via dangerouslySetInnerHTML, and all is fine when the page is navigated to directly. However when the app's routing is used and a full page refresh doesn't happen the script tag is included in the markup, but not executed.

The following example is using the default Next.JS blog example here: https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/tree/master/basics-final.

Markdown:

```
---
title: "Example of GIST embedding"
date: "2020-02-20"
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id arcu at arcu pretium porta. Nam feugiat est ut lectus imperdiet venenatis. Ut tempus vitae lectus id vestibulum. Sed tristique est metus. Ut pretium malesuada risus. Maecenas eget diam tristique, sagittis velit ac, efficitur nisi. Quisque lectus lorem, vehicula at mi vitae, dapibus volutpat augue. Sed dignissim pharetra ligula a efficitur. In ultrices imperdiet libero. Quisque ornare erat eu elit ullamcorper faucibus. Maecenas mattis sem a mauris posuere iaculis.

<script src="https://gist.github.com/robearlam/aec15c65aaffbd5ec00a826c5cbe57ad.js"></script>

Etiam sed interdum ligula, nec tincidunt justo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce in scelerisque nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis lectus at ligula mollis dapibus. Praesent condimentum metus fringilla, commodo enim non, fringilla dui. Vivamus nec ligula lacinia ante semper rhoncus eu sed nisi. In ac dolor vel lorem tincidunt lacinia. Praesent quis mattis mi, at finibus velit. Etiam auctor, magna fermentum tincidunt interdum, nulla augue porttitor enim, ac lobortis felis eros id dui. Suspendisse dignissim, dui sit amet pulvinar iaculis, nisi tellus rhoncus dolor, eu gravida risus massa accumsan magna.
```

Page

```
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import { getAllPostIds, getPostData } from '../../lib/posts'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Date from '../../components/date'
import utilStyles from '../../styles/utils.module.css'

export default function Post({ postData }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{postData.title}</title>
      </Head>
      <article>
        <h1 className={utilStyles.headingXl}>{postData.title}</h1>
        <div className={utilStyles.lightText}>
          <Date dateString={postData.date} />
        </div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData.contentHtml }} />
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getAllPostIds()
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postData = await getPostData(params.id)
  return {
    props: {
      postData
    }
  }
}
```

Lib function

```
export async function getPostData(id) {
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`)
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

  // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
  const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

  // Use remark to convert markdown into HTML string
  const processedContent = await remark()
    .use(html)
    .process(matterResult.content)
  const contentHtml = processedContent.toString()

  // Combine the data with the id and contentHtml
  return {
    id,
    contentHtml,
    ...matterResult.data
  }
```

I also have a repo showing the issue here: https://github.com/robearlam/gist-embedding-issue

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, [I found this post to be very helpful](https://thetombomb.com/posts/adding-code-snippets-to-static-markdown-in-Next%20js).

Basically, you create a custom code block that formats your code tags inline.

It has you use `<ReactMarkdown>` component to render your markdown (instead of remark) and then you use the react-syntax-highlighter library in your custom code block component.

When rendering your markdown use:

```
import CodeBlock from "../../components/codeblock"

<ReactMarkdown components={CodeBlock}>{your markdown data here}</ReactMarkdown>
```

Importing your custom codeblock component for the markdown processor.

Tom's custom code block example below:

```
// components/codeblock.js
import React from "react"
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter"
import {dracula} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism';

const CodeBlock = {
  code({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
    const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '')
    return !inline && match ? (
    <SyntaxHighlighter 
      style={dracula} 
      language={match[1]} 
      PreTag="div" {...props}>
      {String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>

    ) : (
      <code className={className} {...props}>
        {children}
      </code>
    )
  }
}

export default CodeBlock
```